# Почему не работает условие с or?

Tags: c++

Почему не работает условие с or?

При делении выводится результат умножения, а не деления.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    cout << "Калькулятор" << endl;
    cout << "Введите первое число: ";
    int first;
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Введите второе число: ";
    int second;
    cin >> second;
    cout << "Введите действие: ";
    string dosomething;
    cin >> dosomething;
    if (dosomething == "+")
        cout << first + second << endl;
    else if (dosomething == "-")
        cout << first - second << endl;
    else if (dosomething == "*" or "x")
        cout << first * second << endl;
    else if (dosomething == "/" or "÷" or ":")
        cout << first / second << endl;
    else 
        cout << "ошибка" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Не задавайте вопросы картинками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**!!

И еще — если вы считаете, что `if (a == b or c)` сравнивает `a` с `b` и `c`, то вы таки неправы. Это выражение читается как "если `a` равно `b` или `c` не равно нулю". Естественно, что `'x'` никак не равно нулю, так что отрабатывает умножение.

То, что вы хотите, надо проверять как

```
if (a == b || a == c)
```

А вот если бы вы дали свой пример текстом, я бы скопипастил и исправил именно вашу строку :)

Comment: вот код https://pastebin.com/Pz6H2X0p (он был приложен в вопросе)

Comment: Ссылки точно так же не приветствуются. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным.